# Meteor Images, CSS, "Normal" Web Serving

Tags: image, web-services, http, meteor

I've seen this question come up a lot;

- How do I put images on my Meteor website?
- How do I host "standard" web content with Meteor?
- I tried adding a `<img src="img/myimage.png">` tag but no image shows!
- How can I host some files on a Meteor site?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Put the content in a folder named "public" in your project root.**

- You do not need to include /public in your URLs.
- Any additional folder structure within public is supported.
- NodeJS routing plugins are not required, as other answers have supplied.
- Place external library's javascript files in /lib. They will be automatically included.

---

**Explanation**

In Meteor, you can host "standard" web content by creating a "public" directory in the root of your project. Any images, files, or data you place in this folder will be served as normal by the NodeJS server, as if they were in the root of the server.

---

***Example***

- Structure within project: */public/test/img.png*
- Corresponding image URL: */test/img.png*
- Example HTML tag: `<img src="/test/img.png"/>`

Comment: just wanted to add, the **/** at the beginning is important.

Comment: From what I've been able to find for documentation this in Meteor is if you don't want the page to be refreshed every time a file in a folder changes, add "~" to the end of the folder or file.

If I do this, the above examples stop working!

Comment: @Dave Adding ~ to the end of something indicates it's a temporary file, which Meteor ignores. This is standard naming convention on linux. Please don't intentionally add a ~ to the end of your project files..

Comment: I have it so the server can save images into the public folder, but the server restarts each time it does! Will this happen in production?

Comment: @nearpoint It won't happen in production but that's also the wrong way to go about storing and serving dynamic images.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder **`public`** inside the project directory. Add a new folder **`img`** (or any other name of your choice) inside the public folder. Copy all the images that you require to be added in to your HTML into this folder.

Now you can use it like - `<img src="img/myimage.png">`

You don't need to include /public in the in the URL.

Comment: Did you see the existing answer or did you just decide to post the same thing