# Linking to assets in the public folder in Meteor.js and Telescope

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, assets, telescope

I am using Telescope on Meteor and I am having trouble accessing anything that's in my public folder. In my Meteor app I have a package that has a public folder - that has images/fonts that I am failing to link to properly.

I am new to Meteor and Telescope so I think I am messing up something basic. These is what I am working with:

File structure path to `/public`:

```
MyApp/Packages/ThemeName/public/
```

Which contains three folders: `icons`, `images`, and `fonts`.

To link to my fonts in my CSS, I am using `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Neuzeit; 
    src:
    url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.css"),
    url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.eot"),
    url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.svg"),
    url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.ttf"),
    url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.woff");
}
body {
    font-family: Neuzeit;
}
```

But these fonts don't load and I receive an error in my console: `Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/neuzeit-book.ttf [index:1]`. I get this for each of those sources. Additionally, I have also attempted to link to images in my templates within the same package:

```
<img src="/icons/icon-close.png" />
```

But then I get a broken link icon instead of that image on the page - and oddly, no 404 for the image in the console.

Is this a permissions issue? I have referred to [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166566/meteor-images-css-normal-web-serving) but this ended up being irrelevant as I believe I'm writing the correct paths right? Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/public` needs to be at the root of your app, not under `/Packages/ThemeName/public/`

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to the wrong URL:
Instead of this:

```
url("/fonts/neuzeit-book.css")
```

It should be something like this:

```
url("/packages/your-theme-name/public/fonts/neuzeit-book.css")
```

But you should make sure that it is being included via addFiles() in your package.js file